# Journey Builder: Failed - ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Events.Event.FilterResult: Error binding data bound member

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, journeybuilder

I created a Journey Builder Interaction

The Event Source for the interaction is "Date Based Event"

but i have this error message:

> Failed - ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Events.Event.FilterResult: Error binding data bound member

Comment: When exactly do you get this error message? On save, on activation or something else?

Comment: Generally, this error means the audiences in your journey is not part of your All Subscribers list. Check it in Allsub once.

Comment: Abishek is correct. This is the typical error you'd get where the ContactKey cannot be located in a Population - All Subscribers or a data extension defined as a Population in Contact Builder.